# How to disable explicit typing for a certain interface

Tags: typescript, typing

I have an error renderer function in my project.
It creates two functions

```
res.errorJson // Will only send a JSON body to the client
res.error // Will send an HTML error if the client is a browser. Otherwise we'll send json
```

*Before you ask, yes I made sure to add types for these two functions in `express.d.ts`*

`res.error` takes two parameters, first one is the status code, and the second one is the parameters we want to send in the response.

This is my interface for errorOptions

```
// res.error(statuscode: number, options: errorOptions)
declare interface errorOptions {
  title?: string;
  description?: string | Array<string>;
  customHTML?: string;
  jsonOnly?: boolean
}
```

Lets say call res.error with an additional option thats not inside the interface, typescript will yell at me

I want to disable explicit typing for this ONE interface.

Basically just so I have the pretyped types in the interface, and if I want to add something else to the options, I can do so without typescript yelling at me. I hope this makes sense and I hope I'm not dumb

Here is all my code for my error renderer

```
res.errorJson = (statusCode: RangeOf2<100,599>, options?: errorOptions) => {
    options.jsonOnly = true;
    return res.error(statusCode, options);
  };
  res.error = (statusCode: RangeOf2<100,599>, options?: errorOptions) => {
    if (typeof(statusCode) !== "number") {
      throw new Error("Status code is not a number");
    }

    options = options || {};
    
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(errors, statusCode)) {
      options.title = errors[statusCode];
    } else {
      options.title = options.title || `${statusCode} Not defined`; 
    }

    if (req.useragent.isBot !== false || options.jsonOnly === true) {
      
      let data = {
        success: false
      };

      for (const v in data) {
        console.log(v);
      }

      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
      // @ts-ignore ignore this until espi gets back to me
      data.success = false;

      res.send(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + "\n");
      return data;
    }
    ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, "errorTemplate.ejs"), {data: options}).then(render => {
      try {
        res.status(statusCode).send(render);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("You are sending an error after headers were sent to the client.");
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
    return options;
  };
  next();
```

Comment: Can you reword this? It's a little confusing. It sounds like you want something that's unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you should be able to declare your interface to accept arbitrary parameters:

```
declare interface errorOptions {
  title?: string;
  description?: string | Array<string>;
  customHTML?: string;
  jsonOnly?: boolean;
  [x: string]: any;
}
```

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#strict-object-literal-assignment-checking

"If the target type accepts additional properties, add an indexer"